# Should I transliterate for localizing profile information / website content

Tags: java, jsp, localization, transliteration

I want to implement localization in my website, which is in JSP. How should I localize the content that is stored in table?

1. Should I store data in different languages itself in table
2. If yes how should I accept input data?
3. Or should I accept data and store in English and transliterate while displaying that content.

Website UI can be localized easily, but am quite confused about content that is stored in database.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of data you are referring to?

Comment: Ohkay say I have to display information of various books in tabular grid. So I want to display the names in different languages based on locale.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Create a different `Books` table for each language. And store all the data for each book there.
2. Create a single `Books` table with secondary keys into `Titles`, `Authors`, etc. tables. These secondary tables then store the translated versions of each string. This suggestion has the advantage of not duplicating data that doesn't need to be translated (such as the ISBN number).

Comment: What is done in production environment? I see we cannot search Amazon and Wikipedia by other languages. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Your original question does not include anything about searching. What are all of the requirements which are relevant to your current problem?

Comment: just wanted to know what all things are possible. Actually curious about knowing how Google performs whole bunch of functionality:
1.  Take English Input
2.  search if pages with preferred lang exists, if yes provide search suggestions in that lang
3.  if not provide English suggestion

Am just exploring things. **More interested in knowing if there are any frameworks, plugins, APIs** General direction or possible/standard approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: And yes how can I store data in all those required language when I am actually accepting data in English?